# cmus ignore ID3 tags, rely on folder structure

Tags: music, id3, cmus

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
Music
└── Artist_1
|   └── Album_A
|       └── track_w.mp3
└── Artist_2
|   └── Album_B
|       └── track_x.mp3
└── Podcasts
    └── Podcast_A
    |   └── podtrack_y.mp3
    └── Podcast_B
        └── podtack_z.mp3
```

In essence, `Podcasts` is treated like and Artist, and the Podcast name (`Podcast_A`) is treated as an album.

Is there a way to get cmus to respect this folder structure when building the library? At the moment, `Podcast_A` is treated as an artist, but sometimes other podcasts are treated as `<No Name>`.

I expect this has something to do with ID3 tagging. Is there a way to entirely disable the reading of ID3 tags in cmus?